# Office Add-in promises resolving only when mouse hovers add-in taskpane

Tags: office-js

I am developping an add-in that will query the Excel object model when the user changes its selection within the active worksheet.

During testing, I sometimes encounter an issue that makes the promises not resolving until I move the mouse pointer over the add-in task pane. More specifically, the first command declared within Excel.run batch is not even evaluated client-side at first (when the mouse is still over the excel document), but it gets evaluated as soon as the mouse hovers the task pane.

I am testing on Windows 10 anniversary update with Excel 2016 and have Edge (14) but it appears that the Excel Add-in is leveraging IE11 engine instead. In this situation, the es6-promise library is what provides the promises implementation using the DOM MutationObserver API.

Their library looks good. Someone filled an issue in the past (https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/109), it had something to do with IE11 and MutationObservers but it looks that it was resolved on IE's side. There must still be an issue with MutationObservers but I have troubles identifying what the root cause is.

Here is some code if you want to test it yourself :

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded.
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, function () {

                var values = [
                    [Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)],
                    [Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)],
                    [Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)]
                ];

                Excel.run(function (ctx) {
                    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
                    sheet.getRange("B3:D5").values = values;
                    return ctx.sync();
                })
                .catch(errorHandler);
            });

        });
    }

    // Helper function for treating errors
    function errorHandler(error) {
        showNotification("Error", error);
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    }
})();
```

I often have a lot of tabs opened in internet explorer, some of them might have a debugger attached or developper tools opened but I am really not sure what triggers this behaviour.

As per my "question" itself, if the issue is confirmed, do you know if there is a way to use Edge instead of IE11 to execute the Office Add-in, or know if another implementation of es6-promise may be used other than the one using the MutationObserver API ?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't a way to require a specific browser or browser via an add-in. Does the cause of the selection change have any impact? Curious if there is any connection between the reason the selection changed and the behavior you are seeing (i.e. drag & drop vs simple cell selection).

Comment: No, I don't see any connection between the way I interact with the workbook when changing the selection and the behaviour I am seeing. In my real world add-in I select both ranges and single cells depending on what I want to do, while when I am using this sample I only do single cell selections. Actually, I think batches launched at intervals using setInterval would

Comment: Actually, I think batches launched at intervals would exhibit the same behaviour but it would not be as representative of a real use case as doing queries based on user selection, the key element about issue being the fact that the user does not have its mouse pointer above the add-in task pane as opposed to clicking on a button within the add-in for example.

Comment: I will try to reproduce the issue with a setInterval too to see if there is a relation between javascript timers and MutationObservers queue flushing, because I am wondering if it can have something to do with some throttling introduced to save energy as it is known to happen with javascript timers.

Comment: I got the same issue again this afternoon and I was able to test a few more things. Interestingly, javascript timers look OK while promises still get stuck, but setInterval seems to help mitigating the issue, even when doing "nothing", as it triggers a flush on MutationObservers queue exactly as if I was moving my mouse over the task pane.

Comment: I am getting short on new test cases that would show there is a quirk in MutationObservers using pure web developer techniques and I wonder if it only happens when the browser component is embedded in a host application. I will keep you updated with whatever I find.